# HTML - PHP - onclick() submit button to update value in SQL Server

Tags: php, html

I have a button on HTML:

```
<input class="endthischat" name="endthischat" type="submit" 
       id="endthischat" onclick="setuserlogout()" value="End This Chat" />
```

When the button clicked, it supposed to call a function to send a session `$chatwith` as parameter to update some value in database SQL Server.

Please also find the function below:

```
<?php
    function setuserlogout(){
        $query3 = "UPDATE users SET isActive = (?) WHERE user_email = (?)";
        $var3 = array("0",$chatwith);

        if($chatwith !=""){
            sqlsrv_query($conn, $query3, $var3);
            sqlsrv_close( $conn ); // Close the connection
        }else{
            $message = "wrong answer";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

However, the button doesn't success in calling the function. Please kindly help me and thanks for your time.

Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function setuserlogout(){
          $("#endthischat").click(function(){   
            function() {setuserlogout()};
          })
      };
    </script>
```

Comment: Add your javascript code here

Comment: PHP functions cannot be referenced directly in your HTML as you are attempting here - you need to invoke a javascript function ( ajax most likely ) to initiate the PHP function serverside

Comment: javascript added. Well, I think my problem is in my javascript, isn't it? :(

Comment: From the JavaScript function we can't call a php function and also the JavaScript  function has some errors.

Comment: If the inner `setuserlogout()` is a reference to your php function that will also not work. You need to send a request from the client to the server to actually invoke the php function - usually this is done with ajax but it could be a form submission

Comment: That's the problem, I don't quite understand ajax. Can someone please give me an example of ajax code for calling php function? Thank you so much.

Comment: Main thing you need to understand - PHP is **server side** and runs *before* the HTML is generated. The HTML and JavaScript are **client side** and can't 'see' server-side code. (notice if you view source code you can't actually see any of your PHP?). To get around this you have to send a request to a PHP file that will run and return a value. That value is then passed back in the request response and can be read by your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An untested example of how you could use ajax to send the request to the server and run the sql commands if applicable. Send a simple message in reqponse back to the ajax callback function.

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST['chatwith'] ) ){

        $chatwith = $_POST['chatwith'];


        if( !empty( $chatwith ) ){
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET isActive = ? WHERE user_email = ?";
            $params = array("0",$chatwith);

            sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
            sqlsrv_close( $conn );

            $message='ok';
        } else {
            $message = "wrong answer";
        }

        /* send message to ajax callback function */
        exit( $message );
    }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>simple ajax example</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>

            function ajax(m,u,p,c,o){
                /*
                    Method,Url,Params,Callback,Options
                */
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )c.call( this, xhr.response, o, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() );
                };

                var params=[];
                for( var n in p )params.push(n+'='+p[n]);

                switch( m.toLowerCase() ){
                    case 'post': p=params.join('&'); break;
                    case 'get': u+='?'+params.join('&'); p=null; break;
                }

                xhr.open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( p );
            }


            function setuserlogout(){
                var chatwith=document.getElementById('chatwith');

                var method='post';
                var url=location.href;
                var params={ chatwith:chatwith.value };
                var callback=function(r,o,h){
                                                o.output.innerHTML=r;
                                            };
                var options={ output:document.getElementById('results') };

                /* send the ajax request to the same page ( or other ) */
                ajax.call( this, method, url, params,callback, options );
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='text' name='chatwith' id='chatwith' />
        <input class="endthischat" name="endthischat" type="submit" id="endthischat" onclick="setuserlogout()" value="End This Chat" />
        <div id='results'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wah, you're the best. Your code is perfectly works for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`onclick="setuserlogout()"` is an event of javascript and you are creating a function of php.

you can do it like this:

```
 <script>
   function setuserlogout(){ 
     <?php //start php tags and write your code here  

     ?>
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: I tried to insert the function that I wrote above into the script as you said, but sorry, it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: I can see some issue with your function too..write a plain query first without binding params and see if it is working, if yes, that means there is an issue in binding

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='text' value = <php  echo $chatwith; ?>  name = 'chatwith' id = 'chatwith'>   
<input class="endthischat" name="endthischat" type="submit"id="endthischat" onclick="setuserlogout()" value="End This Chat" />
```

Javascript

```
 <script>
   function setuserlogout(){ 
      var chatwith = document.getElementById(chatwith);
      // Add ajax code here
   }
 </script>
```

Your function (Consider this is in another file)

```
<?php
    $chatwith = $_POST['chatwith'];
    setuserlogout($chatwith);
    function setuserlogout($chatwith){
        $query3 = "UPDATE users SET isActive = (?) WHERE user_email = (?)";
        $var3 = array("0",$chatwith);

        if($chatwith !=""){
            sqlsrv_query($conn, $query3, $var3);
            sqlsrv_close( $conn ); // Close the connection
        }else{
            $message = "wrong answer";
            //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```